# Universal cover of boundary

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, geometric-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a compact manifold-with-boundary and $B$ a component of $\partial M$. Let $\tilde{M}$ be the univeral cover of $M$ with infinite-sheeted covering map $p:\tilde{M} \to M$. I wonder about the following: Is it true that each component of $p^{-1}(B)$ is a universal covering space of $B$ ?

Answer (score 3):

No, this would imply that the boundary of a simply connected manifold is simply connected. But this isn't true for a number of reasons; there's the disc $D^2$, say. If you demand higher-dimensional things, simply connected 3-manifolds have simply connected boundary automatically, but as soon as you're in dimension 4 there are contractible manifolds whose boundaries are not $S^3$. (If its boundary was $S^3$, by the same circle of ideas we've talked about before, you could prove the manifold was homeomorphic to $D^4$.) These are called [Mazur manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold) and are popular objects of study.

The components of $p^{-1}(B)$ *are*, in general, covering spaces of $B$. You can prove this by hand. But they won't necessarily be the universal cover.

Comment: I forgot to exclude the, in some sense degenerate, example of a 2-disk. I didnt know about mazur manifolds and it was great of you to bring this up! Even more enlightening was your information about simply connected 3 manifolds-with-boundary, since this is where my question originally came from. I will start by looking into some long exact homotopy sequences, I guess. Thanks

Comment: @Berni: Actually, think about homology instead. We have good tools to study the homology of the boundary. What fails in higher dimensions is the existence of non-simply connected homology spheres.

Comment: Lefschetz - duality provides the perfect Tool to show your claim for *compact* 3 manifolds-with-boundary. Any clue on how to proceed in the general case ?

Comment: Hmm, the general case is wrong. Take $D^2 \times \Bbb R$. If you demand that the annulus is not a component of the boundary it should be correct and I can write down a proof later.

Comment: Only if you really feel like it. Otherwise i would be perfectly happy to her just some clues

Comment: As long as the homology of the boundary is at least rank 2, the inclusion should induce a nontrivial map, by fiddling with relative homology long exact sequences. I don't remember the details but do think this should be true for noncompact manifolds and not just compact ones.

Comment: My claim is false. Take the closed upper half space and delete some balls that include part of the boundary for counterexamples. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can strengthen your assumptions a little. What if we would demand our boundary to cover a closed, orientable surface ?

Comment: The given example does that, I think. I don't know if the whole manifold covers a compact manifold, though.